# Numpy fromfile function does not work properly

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy

So i'm working on a code where i need to write and read files. I'm using python and numpy, but the numpy fromfile function does not seem to work propperly. First i create an array with 500 elements, and save it with the savetxt function. I check the file and it is all right, just how i wanted.

```
import numpy as np 

w = np.zeros(500, float)
np.savetxt("weights.txt", weight, '%.100f', )
print(weight[2])
```

But after i change the line where i create the array with the one where i read it from a file a problem accours. The zeros turn into really small numbers. I can't guess why. Here is the line where i read from file:

```
weight = np.fromfile("weights.txt", float, -1)
```

Should i write a custom function that turns files into arrays or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Your code save numbers using ascii  and reads them in as floats.  The function you want is `np.loadtxt`.

Comment: Look at `weights.txt`.  Make sure you understand what it is.  `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` are the best tools for reading a test `csv` file.  As you call it `fromfile` is trying to read the file as binary, not text.

Comment: `np.fromfile` reads text files only if given a `sep` parameter.  Review its docs.